# Can I smb into a windows file share without a password?

Tags: smb

I have a macbook running 10.6 and a desktop running win 7.  I would like to smb from my macbook into my win 7 machine.  The problem is that the only way I can smb into my windows machine is if I put a password on the win 7 user account.

I use that machine as a media server, file server, and web server.  I often do work on it remotely.  So I prefer that it does not have a password so if I restart it remotely it will boot back into windows and not just a login screen.

Anyway to smb into a windows machine without a password??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, either enable guest access or just force it to assume the identity of a certain user.

google it and you'll find many examples.

http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/96509133/m/742006210831

Comment: How do I enable guest access?  I do not see it anywhere in the sharing and permission options.  What do you mean force it to assume the identity?

Comment: To enable guest access: share the folder to everyone in r/w mode (but I think that's not a good idea). "Force to assume the identity" means "save the username and password" for the destination pc in the source pc

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I know exactly what you are trying to do.
What you need to do is to have the password on your windows machine anyway and bypass the login.

If you go to "Run" and then type "control userpasswords2" it will bring up a dialog box for passwords. Simply untick the box to request user passwords on login and it will then ask for the default login and the password.

From here on out, it will always log in as that user on reboot allowing you to always connect with SMB.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, you specifically can't connect to a Windows 7 (or Server 2008) machine using an account with a blank password. As such, I think the answer is "no", but using the Guest account may work - I haven't got such a machine to try with at the moment.